# Using a quicksort in c-99

Tags: c, c99

I am using the following quicksort in c-99 script.

The problem is that it compiles but it does not have any output. I am trying to sort 5,4,3,2,1 into 1,2,3,4,5 I only get nothing.

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

this be my code

```
\\pick a pivot
\\make a temporary left and right list
\\filter items to left and to the right
\\put it all back into the array left and pivot
\\recurse right side


#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void subquicksort(int array[], int start, int end){

    int leng=end-start;
    if (leng<=1){
        return;
    }

    int pivot=array[start];
    int leftlist[leng];      \\create temporary left and right list
    int lindex=0;
    int rightlist[leng];
    int rindex=0;

    for(int i=start + 1; i < leng; i++){

        if(array[i]<pivot) {
            leftlist[lindex++]=array[i];
        }
        else{
            rightlist[rindex++]=array[i];
        }
    }

    array[start + lindex]=pivot;

    for( int i=start +1; i <leng; i++){

        if (i<lindex){
            array[start + i]=leftlist[i];
        }
        if(i==lindex){
            continue;
        }
        if(i>lindex){
            array[start + i]=rightlist[i-lindex-1];
        }
    }

    subquicksort(array,start,start+lindex);
    subquicksort(array,start+lindex+1,end);
}

void quicksort(int array[],int leng){
    subquicksort(array,0,leng);
}



int main(){

    int nums[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    quicksort(nums, 5); \\use the quicksort function and print out the values sorted
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("%d",nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the *standard* [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html). If it is a homework: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Yes, your code is very difficult on the eyes.

Comment: Ok I will try to format

Comment: 1)at 1st for-loop `for(int i=start + 1; i < leng; i++){` : `i < leng;` should be `i < end` 2) `i<6` --> `i<5`

Comment: 3) at 2nd for-loop `leftlist[i];` : `i` start from 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void subquicksort(int array[], int start, int end){
    int leng=end-start;

    if(leng<=1){
        return;
    }

    int pivot=array[start];
    int leftlist[leng];
    int lindex=0;
    int rightlist[leng];
    int rindex=0;

    for(int i=start + 1; i < end; i++){
        if(array[i]<pivot) {
            leftlist[lindex++ ]=array[i];
        } else {
            rightlist[rindex++]=array[i];
        }
    }

    array[start + lindex]=pivot;

    for( int i=0; i < lindex; i++)
        array[start + i]=leftlist[i];
    for(int i=0; i < rindex; i++)
        array[start + lindex + 1 + i]=rightlist[i];

    subquicksort(array,start,start+lindex);
    subquicksort(array,start+lindex+1,end);
}

void quicksort(int array[],int leng){
    subquicksort(array,0,leng);
}

int main(){
    int nums[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    quicksort(nums, 5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though you probably fixed the issue, code only answers are frowned upon, and this is long enough that I find it difficult to immediately spot what changed.  You should probably copy your comments to the answer if that's all you changed.

Comment: @MooingDuck Already comment on the problems (ie fixes). Was too severe to cite the original code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I see yes my second for loop should be i<5 because arrays start at zero, thanks for pointing out my various errors